# Summing the ints in a string using scanner.chopper: java

Tags: java

first post on this site, so, I essentially have to find a way to **chop up** the ints in a string, divided only by spaces, (**example would be ("9 10 5 20 1 2 3") and then find the sum of all of the chopped up ints**.  I know i have to use **chopper.nextInt()**, but I am not sure how to format the totality of the code, along with summing the output after. Thanks so much!

import static java.lang.System.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class LineTotaller
{
    private String line;

```
public LineTotaller()
{
    setLine("");
}

public LineTotaller(String s)
{setLine(s);
}

public void setLine(String s)
{line = s;
}

public int getSum()
{

  int sum = 0;
    Scanner chopper = new Scanner(line);
    while(chopper.hasNextInt())
    { 
        out.print(chopper.nextInt());

        sum+= //returned ints from above


    }

}
public String getLine()
{
    return "";
}

public String toString()
{
    return getLine();
}
```

}

Comment: Show your attempt? I mean the code you have tried so far....

Comment: please share your work to proceed helping.

Comment: At this point your getting many downvotes. As your new try to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to improve your question.

Comment: added the work I have

Comment: What (or where) is `chopper`?

Comment: I added it and changed some of the code I had.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do the following

```
public int getSum()
{
    int sum = 0;
    Scanner chopper = new Scanner(line);
    while(chopper.hasNextInt())
    {
        int nextInt = chopper.nextInt();
        System.out.print(nextInt);
        sum += nextInt;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You can only call `nextInt` once after you confirmed that there is something via `hasNextInt`. If you want to print it and add it to the sum, you have to store the value temporarily in a variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely blanked out and forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the string.split() method to place you numbers string into a string array then iterate through the array with a 'for loop', convert each element to a integer ( Integer.valueOf() )and maintain a ongoing total with each iteration.

Something like:

```
String yourString = "9 10 5 20 1 2 3";
String[] myNumbers = yourString.split(" ");
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myNumbers.length; i++) {
    total+= Integer.valueOf(myNumbers[i]);
}

System.out.println("Total is: -> " + total);
```

That should get it done for you.